# Smooth monotonically decreasing function to satisfy various constraints.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials

thanks in advance for reading.

I need to find a function, f(x), which is smooth and monotonically decreasing over the domain a < x < d, and satisfies various requirements. The requirements are stated in terms of variables a, b, c, d, and e where these variables can take any value satisfying:

a < b < d,

0 < e < c < 1

I need to be able to express the coefficients of the function in terms of the variables a through e. The requirements for the function are as follows:

f (a) = 1

f ' (a) = 0

f (b) = c

f '' (b) = 0

f (d) = e

f ' (d) = 0

What I'm asking is not for the complete function, I can solve a linear system to find the coefficients in terms of the variables. What I want to know is what form the function will take. Can it be a simple polynomial? And if so what is the minimum order polynomial that will satisfy my requirements?

Comment: Polynomials of a fixed degree tend to become ill-conditioned when points cluster together e.g. $a$ very close to $b$, or $e$ to $c$. One thing to maybe notice, however, is that the shape of function resembles $\cos x$ on $[0,\pi]$. Perhaps you could use that to shift, scale and "compress" it to match the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have $6$ equations to satisfy. We can expect for at least some values of $a,b,c,d,e$, these equations will be independent. In order to solve $6$ independent equations, you need at least $6$ degrees of freedom. I.e., the simplest you can expect $f$ to be is a $5^{th}$ degree polynomial, since that has $6$ coefficients you can set.

So assume that $f(x) = Ax^5 + Bx^4 + Cx^3 + Dx^2 + Ex + F$. Then your equations are:
$$Aa^5 + Ba^4 + Ca^3 + Da^2 + Ea + F= 1\\
Ab^5 + Bb^4 + Cb^3 + Db^2 + Eb + F= c\\
Ad^5 + Bd^4 + Cd^3 + Dd^2 + Ed + F = e\\
A5a^4 + B4a^3 + C3a^2 + D2a + E = 0\\
A5d^4 + B4d^3 + C3d^2 + D2d + E = 0\\
A20b^3 + B12b^2 + C6b + D2 = 0$$

Note that this a system of 6 linear equation in the 6 unknowns $A, B, C, D, E, F$. Except in degenerate cases, it will have a unique solution, which will provide your quintic polynomial $f$.

However, this does not guarantee that this $f$ will be decreasing. To assure this, you might need to allow for additional inflection points, say a degree 7 polynomial.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this. So with a 7-degree polynomial, how would I ensure that the function is decreasing? I need to be able to do this programmatically.